# Вывод строки типа TIME из sql в питоне

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

пытаюсь вывести таблицу через питон

```
    def verification():
    connection = DataBase.getConnection_log()
    try:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # SQL 
            text = "SELECT* FROM message"
            cursor.execute(text)    
            for row in cursor:
                print (row)  
    finally:
        connection.close() 
verification()
```

На выходе получается строка

```
{'id': 'admin', 'reconnect_internet': '0', 'reconnect_mqtt': '0', 'open_amount': '2', 'date': datetime.date(2020, 1, 13), 'time': datetime.timedelta(0, 31420)}
```

Нужно корректное отображения даты и времени в формате date: 2020-1-13, time 21:00:18

Типы данных в таблице

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reconnect_internet | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reconnect_mqtt     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| open_amount        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date               | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time               | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в `SELECT` менять вывод строк, указав для столбцов `date` и `time` формат, либо при получении результата sql-запроса изменить данные.

Например, для `datetime.date` можно использовать метод [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), а для `datetime.timedelta` могу предложить [ручной перевод секунд в время](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f0403620f7948306ad9e34a373f2aabc0237fb2a/seconds_to_str.py#L7):

```
def seconds_to_str(seconds) -> str:
    hh, mm = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    mm, ss = divmod(mm, 60)
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)
...

for row in cursor:
    row['date'] = row['date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    row['time'] = seconds_to_str(row['time'].total_seconds())
    print(row)
```

---

**PS.**

Первый способ через `SELECT` можно упростить через добавление своих функций через [create_function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function), тогда их можно вызвать в запросе и вернуть данные в  том виде, что нужен

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно преобразовать date и timedelta в строки:

```
str(datetime.date(2020, 1, 13)) # Получится 2020-01-13
str(datetime.timedelta(0, 31420)) # получится 8:43:40
```

Comment: timedelta может удивить, когда промежуток больше дня :) `>>> str(datetime.timedelta(0, 31420 * 10))
'3 days, 15:16:40'
` . Хотя это маловероятно -- ведь дату с временем в одной записи пишут :)